# How can I protect row height when I hide div

Tags: css, angular

I have a angular 2 component with more then one row. I'm querying the server when any information changes. 
During querying, I want to hide this component and put a progressbar instead, but the progress bar is just one line. 
I want the height of the component to not change when I put the progress bar.

```
<!--when this div hide-->
<div class="form-group row" *ngIf="!condition">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            ROW 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            ROW 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            ROW 3
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--this div show-->
<div class="form-group row" *ngIf="condition">
    Progress bar
</div>
```

Comment: min-height for row will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working [stackblitz repo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-mkkx3c)

You can achieve this by using `ngStyle` directive,

**component.ts**

```
public condition: boolean = true;
```

**component.html**

```
<!--when this div hide-->
<div class="form-group row" [ngStyle]="{'visibility': condition ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            ROW 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            ROW 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            ROW 3
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--this div show-->
<div class="form-group row" *ngIf="condition">
    Progress bar
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`*ngIf="!condition"` doesn't hide an element, it removes it from the DOM completely. You want to apply `visibility: hidden` display property, instead.

```
<div [class.hidden]="condition">...
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

An alternative solution would be to put it in an outer container with defined height (that is, if you can statically define its weight, so: the inner one is of more or less constant size):

```
<div class="spacer">
   <div *ngIf="!condition">Your inner div goes here
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.spacer {
   height: 3rem;
}
```